# google map style - transition between day and night

Tags: json, google-maps

Is there a simple way to create intermediate styles between 'standard' and 'night' found in google's map styling tool: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

After creating a style:

[image]

Clicking on 'FINISH' give the export as JSON option.

[image]

We then copy this JSON for day (based on the 'standard' theme) and then repeat this process for generating the JSON for night.

There isn't a theme generating ability that takes two styles and gives the 'middle' style.

The purpose is to have the map gradually get darker in the evening, and lighter in the morning.  We are using the JSON output, which can be altered manually - however an automatic way would be great.

Comment: what about check current date time when page loading ??

Comment: getting the time is not an issue - it is generating map styles that match with the times around sunset and sunrise and transition smoothly between day ('standard') and night.

Comment: @Vlad is this an Android or JavaScript question?

Comment: Martin - the JSON is used by the google_map() function from the googleway package in R.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a `JSON` `String` with styles there:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    try {

        /* the inital styles to be applied */
        String jsonString = this.getCurrentMapStyles();

        MapStyleOptions style = new MapStyleOptions(jsonString);
        boolean success = map.setMapStyle(style);

        if (! success) {Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");}

    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }

    /* start an update interval timer ... */
}

/* the styles, according to the current time */
private String getCurrentMapStyles() {

    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String jsonString = "";

    /* styles to be generated, with some values mutated */

    return jsonString;
}
```

[Style Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/style-reference)

Comment: loading the styles is not an issue - the issue is in creating the styles

Comment: Martin asked "@Vlad what you mean by "creating the styles"?" - so I've added more information to the question about how we current create the day and night styles - including the export JSON popup.

Comment: using a time-lapse warped timer might be helpful for testing this; I mean, alike `24h` compressed into in `1m`, so that one see the whole progression, at once, in little time. and to compare the night/day theme, you could simply create a `diff` file from these two JSON files, with subversion or git (more reliable and more easy than manual comparison).

Comment: and possibly, even the `MapStyleOptions` could be manipulated directly... while the initial values would always need to match the current time already.